# Thread Wrapper Class for a Function with variable arguments in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multithreading, pthreads, variadic-functions

The idea here is to make a class that constructs with a function and an array of parameters and calls that function in a new thread.

This is my class so far:

```
class FunctionThread extends Thread {

    public function __construct($fFunction, $aParameters){

        $this->fFunction = $fFunction;
        $this->aParameters = $aParameters;
    }

    public function run(){

        $this->fFunction($this->aParmeters[0], $this->aParmeters[1], ...);
    }
}
```

Obviously the run function is incorrect, which brings me to my question:

Assuming the array is guaranteed to have the proper number of elements to match the function that is being called, How can I call a function in PHP with an unknown number of arguments that are stored in an array?

Edit:
Also I have no access to the contents of the given function so it cannot be edited.

Edit 2: I'm looking for something similar to scheme's curry function.

Comment: I'm looking for something like the extract function. but that will push into the scope of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of PHP 5.6, this is now possible. Arrays can be expanded into the argument list using the ... operator like so:

```
<?
class FunctionThread extends Thread {

    public function __construct($fFunction, $aParameters){

        $this->fFunction = $fFunction;
        $this->aParameters = $aParameters;
    }

    public function run(){

        $this->fFunction(... $this->aParmeters);
    }
}
?>
```

See [here](https://www.php.net/functions.arguments#functions.variable-arg-list%20for%20more) for more information

Answer (score 0):

I think that function should accept in its case the arg array

```
class FunctionThread extends Thread {
    public function __construct($fFunction, $aParameters){

        $this->fFunction = $fFunction;
        $this->aParameters = $aParameters;
    }

    public function run(){

        $this->fFunction($this->aParmeters);
    }
    public function fFunction($arr){
        $var0 = $arr[0];
        $var1 = $arr[1];
        ...
        do
        ..
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm trying to completely abstract away the function. If I had access to the source of that function, I would do that, but unfortunately this needs to interact with an API that I can't access. Thank though.