# Store static function of a class in a variable

Tags: php, anonymous-function

In PHP, I have a class that takes in a function object and calls that function in a thread: [see the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25186885/thread-wrapper-class-for-a-function-with-variable-arguments-in-php/25575182#25575182).

It works well with anonymous functions, however, I want to use this functionality with a static function of a different class:

```
    $thThread = new FunctionThreader(OtherClass::static_function, $aParams);
```

This throws an error `Undefined class constant static_function on line x`

I have tried:

```
    $fFunction = OtherClass::static_function;
    $thThread = new FunctionThreader($fFunction, $aParams);
```

And I get the same error.

So is there anyway to store this static function into `$fFunction`or to simply reference it as a function object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP you would usually use a [callback](http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.callable.php) for this:

```
$callback = array('ClassName', 'methodName');
$thThread = new FunctionThreader($callback, $aParams);
```

---

If `FunctionThreader::__construct()` does only accept a `Closure` and you have no influence on it's implementation, then you can wrap the static function call in a `Closure`:

```
$closure = function() { return ClassName::methodName(); };
$thThread = new FunctionThreader($closure, $aParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a lambda function which calls your static function. Or simply store function name as a string in that variable. You would also have to implement a handler code for the class that calls a function from variable.

Resources:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.forward-static-call-array.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php

Example for anonymous function:

```
<?php 

$function = new function(){
   return forward_static_call_array(['class', 'function'], func_get_args());
};

?>
```

Testes this, works flawlessly.